# New to Javascript Making a Tip calculator cant figure out why its not loading?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am new to javascript, I was trying to practice by doing a lab that I saw online and I was following along with the original code posted and I was making my own tweaks at the same time. I finished the html portion and javascript portion but when I hit calculate nothing is happening. I did inspect element went to console and ran it and it showed syntax error but I am unclear where this error is?? this is my code

```html
<DOCTYPE !html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tip.css">
    <title>Tip Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //this is to calculate tip
      function calculateTip() {
        var billAMT = document.getElementBy("billamount").value;
        var serviceQual = document.getElementById("servicequality").value;
        var peopleAmt = document.getElementById("peopleamount").value;

        //to validate input
        if billAmt( === "" || serviceQual == 0) {
          alert("please enter numbers");
          return;
        }

        if (peopleAmt === "" || peopleAmt <= 1) {
          peopleAmt = 1;
          document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("each").style.display = "block";
        }

        // to calculate the tip
        var total = (billAmt * serviceQual) / peopleAmt;

        //to round to two places
        total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
        total = total.toFixed(2);

        // to display tip
        document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;
      }
      document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";

      // to call function
      document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() {
        calculateTip();
      };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1> Tip Calculator</h1>
      <div id="calculator">
        <form>
          <p> Enter bill amount</p>
          <input id="billamount" tyle="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">
          <p>How was your service?</p>
          <select id="servicequality">
            <option value="0.3">30&#37; &#45; Amazingly LITT</option>
            <option value="0.2">20&#37; &#45; Good</option>
            <option value="0.15">15&#37;&#45;Was ight</option>
            <option value="0.10">10&#37;&#45; bad</option>
            <option value="0.05">5&#37;&#45; Terrible</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <p>How many people are sharing the bill?</p>
        <input id="peopleamount" type="text" placeholder="# of people">
        <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
      </div>
      <div id="totalTip">
        <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
        <small id="each">each</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your script.

1. The browser parses your HTML code from top to bottom. That means it processes the `<head>` section before `<body>`.

The JavaScript part is located inside the `<head>` section and put between the opening tag `<script type="text/javascript">`
and the closing tag `</script>`.
If you take a closer look at your JavaScript code you'll find find this two statements:

```
document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";
```

Those aren't inside the scope of the **calculateTip(){}** function nor the **.onclick = function() {}** handler so the browser
tries to execute it. Unfortunately it can't! The two elements it tries to manipulate - **totalTip** & **each** - aren't available
yet since the browser didn't reach the `<body>` section yet where it's actually defined.
So you have two options.

**A**

Move the whole JavaScript block including `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` and anything in-between to the body
section, just above the closing `</body>` tag almost at the end of the file.

**B**

Maybe those two statements belong inside the **.onclick = function() {}** handler. Move it there like:

```
document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";   
calculateTip();
};
```

2. Change this line

`if billAmt( === "" || serviceQual == 0) {`

to this

`if (billAMT == "" || serviceQual == 0) {`

3. Javascript is case-sensitive - meaning bill**Amt** and bill**AMT** are not the same. Change all references to either billAmt or billAMT
4. there is a little typo:

var billAMT = document.getElementBy**Id**("billamount").value;

Comment: Hey thanks I did all the other fixes but was a bit confused about the first one the one where you talk about moving the script.Are you telling me to move the entire script to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You have various minor error such as:

- Putting script the referenced an HTML element before the HTML element itself. Putting it at the bottom of the body fixed it
- Using `document.getElementBy` instead of `document.getElementById`
- Referencing the wrong variable name (declared as `billAMT`, referenced as `billAmt`)
- And some typographical error

```html
<DOCTYPE !html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Tip Calculator</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1> Tip Calculator</h1>
      <div id="calculator">
        <form>
          <p> Enter bill amount</p>
          <input id="billamount" tyle="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">
          <p>How was your service?</p>
          <select id="servicequality">
            <option value="0.3">30&#37; &#45; Amazingly LITT</option>
            <option value="0.2">20&#37; &#45; Good</option>
            <option value="0.15">15&#37;&#45;Was ight</option>
            <option value="0.10">10&#37;&#45; bad</option>
            <option value="0.05">5&#37;&#45; Terrible</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <p>How many people are sharing the bill?</p>
        <input id="peopleamount" type="text" placeholder="# of people">
        <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
      </div>
      <div id="totalTip">
        <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
        <small id="each">each</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //this is to calculate tip
      function calculateTip() {
        var billAmt = document.getElementById("billamount").value;
        var serviceQual = document.getElementById("servicequality").value;
        var peopleAmt = document.getElementById("peopleamount").value;

        //to validate input
        if (billAmt === "" || serviceQual == 0) {
          alert("please enter numbers");
          return;
        }

        if (peopleAmt === "" || peopleAmt <= 1) {
          peopleAmt = 1;
          document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("each").style.display = "block";
        }

        // to calculate the tip
        var total = (billAmt * serviceQual) / peopleAmt;

        //to round to two places
        total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
        total = total.toFixed(2);

        // to display tip
        document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;
      }
      document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";

      // to call function
      document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() {
        calculateTip();
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```